# Django: file upload MemoryError at /some/url

Tags: python, django, file-upload, gunicorn

I get a `MemoryError` exception when I try to upload files more than 2 gigs in size after the deployment on the server but with development server it works fine. 
Application served by Nginx + gunicorn, Nginx limitation for uploaded file size is about 6Gb. 
Below you can see the code fragment which handles uploading

```
destination = tempfile.NamedTempopraryFile(delete=False)
for chunk in f.chunks():
   destination.write(chunk)
destination.close()
```

Can a temporary file cause `MemoryError` exceptions?

Comment: Is your deployment server 32-bit?

Comment: What platforms are the dev server and production server?

Comment: @Chris Lacasse development is going on my macbook production server is running under ubuntu

Comment: Could you provide full stack trace?